# .net core localization set one currency format

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Is there a way to set one standard  currency format and different languages

I want to change the language but not currency in .net core application .
Any ways to implement this.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to explain what you want. You can use different cultures in all formatting and parsing functions. You can configure the CultureInfo all that at the web app, request or thread level. You *can't* create custom CultureInfo objects yet, even though you could in the Full framework. Which cultures are you interested in?

Comment: Malaysia currency and language can english or others...

Comment: Have you checked the available cultures? A culture's name is a combination of language and country. There's `en-MY`, `ms-MY` and `ta-MY` for example. These represent different languages but the currency comes from `MY`, the country

Comment: I have added few Cultures "en-MY","en-US","en-IN",when user select "en-US"  i want the Localiser to switch to english if user choose "en-MY" to Malaysian   
but the currency in both case should be RM(Malaysian) .

Answer (score 1):

In the startup code of your app you can define supported cultures and default culture. 
There are actually 2 culture settings culture, and UI culture. The first one controls numbers, currency, datetime formats and the UI culture controls the string resources, so you could only use a single culture but also support additional UI cultures to let strings be localized while keeping numbers only formatted by just one culture. Some example code:

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedUICultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
        new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
        new CultureInfo("fr"),
    };

    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-GB")

    };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-GB", uiCulture: "en-GB");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedUICultures;


});
```

Comment: if this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as the answer.

Comment: app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture:"en-MY",uiCulture:"en-MY"),
                SupportedCultures = _defalutCulture,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            });

Comment: on post method i am setting culture as

Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
                new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
            );

still no change in Localized string's

Comment: _default is  var _defalutCulture = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-MY")
            };